# Why doesn't Cyanogen support Droid 2 Global (droid2we)?

Tags: cyanogenmod, motorola-droid-2

Why can't I use the latest version of Cyanogen ROM for Droid 2 Global? The latest available version for this phone is CM 7.2, while the current version is 10.2. The [wiki page](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Droid2we_Info) just says 'hardware limitations', but is not explicit. I'm not aware of any limitations other than it might go a bit slower than a new phone.

What would happen if I installed the latest Android Open Source Project on a D2G?

Comment: Why: Because nobody adapted the latest version for your device (it needs to be adjusted for its specific hardware: camera drivers and such). What would happen? It might not boot at all, or it boots but some components don't work. That might be the camera, or even the radios (so you couldn't even call anyone or receive calls).

Comment: The wiki pages says "This may be due to hardware limitations **or simply because development is not yet complete.**". Maybe there is simply no maintainer for Cyanogenmod on the droid2we. Note that simply "installing AOSP on the D2G" will most likely not work or, as Izzy explained, result in some components not working. Creating a ROM for a devices requires many device specific adjustments.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Buy Android phone, install Android from source, have Nexus S -like experience?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12332/buy-android-phone-install-android-from-source-have-nexus-s-like-experience)